# Xcode admin role required?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.2

We have been added as developer to an Apple account of our customer. Since some days, we cannot sign the apps in the uploading process because of:

> "No accounts with the Admin role have been found for ...".
>
> The Admin role is necessary in order to generate signing assets for
>   this archive."

I am pretty sure we will not get the admin role because it is/was simply not necessary for simply uploading a new version of the app.

Anybody facing the same problem on Xcode 10.2?